# Unable to create New User Property in Firebase

Tags: firebase, properties, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

I am unable to create a new user property on Firebase because in this project the button "Create new user property" doesn't appear as it does in other projects, even having Firebase Admin Permissions.

Is it a bug? Can be something related to the project setup? I have no idea what else can be as there is no documentation about it.

Screenshot of the project with no button available:
[image: Screenshot of the project with no button available]

Screenshot of another project with the button available:
[image: Screenshot of another project with the button available]

Answer (score 1):

Per [Firebase-level predefined roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-all-products), Firebase Admin role should have full read/write access to all Firebase services. I tried to replicate this issue on my end, but I am able to see the 'New user property' button with Firebase Admin, Grow Admin, Owner and Editor roles.

I suggest you visit the **users and permissions** tab under **project settings** in the Firebase console and double check if you indeed have the correct permission. If so and still not able to see the 'New user property' button, then file a bug on [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).